# regular expression to match days hours minutes

Tags: javascript, regex

*I have a string that would represents a duration.*
it can be like one of the following :

> **10d12h59m**
>
> **10d12h**
>
> **10d**
>
> **12h**
>
> **70**

number before the "d" represents days ,number before "h" represents hours ,number before "m" represents minutes and if its just number then it means minutes.

I would like a javascript regular expression that will match that string.

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? Do you want to verify the string, or parse it?

Comment: @VisioN i m trying the answers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check if it matches: `/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/`

examples:

```
"10d12h59m".match(/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/); // Array ["10d12h59m"]
"10d12h".match(/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/); // Array ["10d12h"]
"10d".match(/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/); // Array ["10d"]
"12h".match(/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/); // Array ["12h"]
"70".match(/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/); //Array ["70"]

"foobar".match(/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/); // null
"10d50m".match(/^(?:\d+d(?:\d+h(?:\d+m)?)|\d+[dh]?)$/); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(\d\d[dhm]?){1,3}/
```

This will match all of your examples.

How it works:

```
# \d\d   - Match 2 digits
# [dhm]? - followed by a optional d, h, or m.
# {1,3}  - and make sure there's 1, 2 or 3 of the previous.
```

In case you also want to pass single-digit numbers, or numbers above 99, use this regex:

```
/(\d+[dhm]?){1,3}/
//  ^ Note the added +, instead of \d
```

Comment: it is not pass `1d12h59m`, replace `\d?\d` with `\d+`, it may be `111d`

Comment: @burning_LEGION: that wasn't part of the question, but added it in.

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `(\d+[dmh]?)+`

Comment: That'll also match `1d12h59m13` or `1d12h59m01m1d1h`

Comment: and `12h3456`, and `1d1d1d`, by the by your regex too, but other way is set const|const|const f.e. `\d+|\d+d|\d+h`......, i dislike it

Comment: I'm more referring about the fact that it can match a infinite number of letters / digits (the `+` at the end). Didn't think of cases like `1d1d1d`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m?)?/
```

On each of the matched groups, you can easily apply `parseInt(…, 10)`.

Comment: Doesn't match the last letters in: `10d12h, 10d, 12h`.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Oh, right, I was in the wrong belief that minutes were mandatory. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

To parse the strings into hours, days and minutes:

```
function parseDuration(s) {
  var m = /(?:(\d+)d)?(?:(\d+)h)?(?:(\d+)m?)?/.exec(s);
  return {
    days: parseInt(m[1], 10) || 0,
    hours: parseInt(m[2], 10) || 0,
    minutes: parseInt(m[3], 10) || 0
  };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/9hj5F/

#### Edit:

To verify the string, you can use a pattern with the three different variations (dhm, dh and d can all be the same variation, with optional parts) for a basic verifiaction, like: `^(\d+d(\dh(\d+m)?)?|\d+h|\d+m?)$`.

If you also waht to limit the values, you can for example use `[0-5]?\d` instead of `\d+` to limit the value to be 0 to 59, or `[0-5]\d` to require two digits i.e 00-59.